# When i double click on WPF DataGrid row for get cell value, return NULL

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I get this error in my code in `MouseDoubleClick` event.

> Error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgTarafDovvom" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseDoubleClick="dtgTarafAvval_MouseDoubleClick">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TarafeynQarardadID}" Header="کد ">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

*here is my c# code*

```
private void dtgTarafAvval_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, ouseButtonEventArgs e) {
  TarafeynQarardadDTO t = dtgTarafAvval.SelectedItem as TarafeynQarardadDTO;
  int tarafeynID = t.TarafeynQarardadID;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check if your current selected count is not zero, before retrieving the cell content. Just a little code to help you.

```
 private void dtgTarafAvval_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dtgTarafAvval.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            CellValue = GetSelectedValue(dtgTarafAvval);
            //CellValue is a variable of type string.

        }
    }

    private string GetSelectedValue(DataGrid grid)
    {
        DataGridCellInfo cellInfo = grid.SelectedCells[0];
        if (cellInfo == null) return null;

        DataGridBoundColumn column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
        if (column == null) return null;

        FrameworkElement element = new FrameworkElement() { DataContext = cellInfo.Item };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(element, TagProperty, column.Binding);

        return element.Tag.ToString();
    }
```

PS: Above code works for SelectionUnit = 'FullRow'

Comment: You're welcome, please show the community your gratitude by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event for the `DataGridRow` container and cast its `DataContext` property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtgTarafDovvom" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="dtgTarafDovvom_MouseDoubleClick" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TarafeynQarardadID}" Header="کد " />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void dtgTarafAvval_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, ouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
    TarafeynQarardadDTO t = row.DataContext as TarafeynQarardadDTO;
    int tarafeynID = t.TarafeynQarardadID;
}
```

Comment: I test it, but i get same error, System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

row was null.

Comment: int tarafeynID = t.TarafeynQarardadID;, because t return null, so   int tarafeynID become null

Comment: Then you didn't bind the ItemsSource property to an IEnumerable<TarafeynQarardadDTO> ?

Comment: Should work since the DataContext of a row is always the underlying data object. If you put a breakpoint in the event handler, what is the type of row.DataContext?

Comment: I do that bu its return null